# Highcharts Tick Positions are not aligned on multiple Y-axises

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have multiple charts on the same page, and the goal was to have same max values for each of the metrics on all charts to make comparison of charts easier ( https://www.screencast.com/t/vtF6h5ZRWS )

I've tried with max values and min values, but it doesn't works, probably because of multiple y-axises.

Now I'm trying to use tickpositions (which I'm calculating in backend) and passing it to chart. But here is the problem with tick alignment on opposite axes and it appears as shown https://www.screencast.com/t/iwnGOhJFb

Below is the small part of code how I set the tick positions and the fiddle of simpler version of chart that I have (I had more y axis's)

```
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Impressions',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },
        tickPositions: [0, 5500000, 11000000, 15000000]

    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j82oen9c/8/

How can I achieve tick alignments on all y-axis's ?

Comment: The ticks of both axes are not aligned between each other because, it would break the logic of chart in this case. Actually if you would move up a bit the tick with `0.5`, from that moment it won't be the `0.5` but more, approximately `0.75`.

Comment: @daniel_s Tobe more detailed, how ticks were calculating in back-end, it's like a `maxValueOfCurrentAxe / 3`, so basically as for me, ticks should be aligned, because interval will be approximately same, not so different, as they appear in graph.

Comment: So the results are bad, because if you use `maxValueOfCurrentAxe / 3` formula, the ticks should be a bit different than now (`[0, 0.5, 1, 2]`). Actually, you don't need to calculate it in backend. Below I will show you how to calculate it correctly, so please wait for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to align the ticks on both axes, you can use two different approaches.
FIrst one is by define your own `Axis.tickPositioner` function which returns calculated array of tickcs adjusted to your needs.

Moving on, you need to get the same amount of ticks on both axes, and they should lay on the same positions on axes, so the positioner function should receive two arguments - `maxValueOfCurrentAxis` and `tickAmount`. I wrote the function like that:

```
var positioner = function(tAmount, axisMax) {
  var positions = []
  for (var i = 0; i < tAmount; i++) {
    positions.push(Math.round(((axisMax / tAmount) * i) * 100) / 100)
  }
  positions.push(axisMax)
  return function() {
    return positions
  }
}
```

and now, we need to assign this function with specific parameters as the `Axis.tickPositioner`, and define the amount of ticks and max values of both axes:

```
 var tickAmount = 3
 var firstAxisMax = 15000000
 var secondAxisMax = 2

 yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
              format: '{value}',
              style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
              }
            },
            title: {
              text: 'Impressions',
              style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
              }
            },
            tickPositioner: positioner.apply(this, [tickAmount, firstAxisMax]),
          }, { // Secondary yAxis
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            tickPositioner: positioner.apply(this, [tickAmount, secondAxisMax]),
            title: {
              text: 'eCPM',
              style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
              }
            },
            labels: {
              format: '{value} $',
              style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
              }
            },
            opposite: true

          }],
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/vL324nqx/

The second way out of that issue, but not so much adjusted to your needs, is by using `Axis.tickPixelInterval` property on both axes. There is no need to explain it more precisely, because there are clear informations about that in API.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/mqget4hb/

API Reference:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositioner

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPixelInterval

Comment: sorry for late response. Thanks, this works as expected ! Thanks !